# Starting and stopping a service remotely in RHEL/Fedora/CentOS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I have created a service on TerminalB. I can start and stop the service by executing following commands at terminalB. Now I want to start and stop this service on TerminalB by executing a shell script present on another machine TerminalA using ssh or any other possible way.

1. `service servicename stop`
2. //do some file copy
3. `service servicename start`

I have executed below command in `Terminal`. (In remote.sh I just kept `service servicename stop`, but the service is not stopping).

```
ssh user@TerminalB "bash -s" < /home/remote.sh
```

Comment: Is `user` a user who can run `service servicename stop` on `TerminalB`? What output do you get from running that command?

Comment: On a side note, you don't need `bash -s` - You can simply redirect the file to the SSH command.

Comment: You can not, the script must be stored in the machine where it runs.

Comment: pasaba: of course this works; there's nothing that prevents reading from stdin over an ssh connection.  That said, you can't run the `service` command as a non-root user.

Comment: @Pasaba, Larsks, Etan - I am running ssh as a root user. I am not getting any error but the server is not getting stopped.

Comment: @ l0b0 - Can you give an example of the alternative you suggesting.

Comment: " I am running ssh as a root user"  likely on your host, not the remote host.

Comment: Does `ssh user@TerminalB service servicename stop` work for you?

Comment: No, its not working.